# seeking the book Sedei Hemed:

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

All the versions that I see of Sede Hemed or Sdei Chemed are very old and unclear. Does anyone see a nice square print one available for sale? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular print isn't so bad, but it is old. (If you see it in stores you'll notice that the cover is nicer than the inside, the index is also typed). I happen to know that Machon Sde Chemed is working on redoing Sde Chemed completely with footnotes, new typeface, and everything.

Comment: Do they have a website?

Comment: did they?.......